# Pie Graph Legend Limitation on Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, pie-chart

I have encounter a problem when displaying a pie graph with legend, only 1/3 of my legend items was displayed the rest are not included. For example A-Z the pie graph was able to display the slices but on the legend only A-M.

Is there any alternative for this? I tried also the bar graph but on the legend there is no values or percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by resizing the font to the smallest possible size. Thanks to this [link](http://scn.sap.com/message/10037056#10037056)